# How do I count / display the number of each outcome from a random sample?

Tags: r, sample

I'm taking a sample of size 1000 of different (pet) animals.  My code is

```
pet <- sample(c("dog","cat","hamster","goldfish"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

I want to see how many times "dog" was selected, "cat" was selected, etc. I've tried `summary(pet)` but wasn't much help / just told me it is length 1000 and characters.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. You should try at least to inform in which language you are coding.
If it's random distribution the law of large numbers says that, having $n_c$ class, each class has probability $P(c_i) = \frac{1}{n_c}$

Comment: oh,sorry. I'm using R. So when I run the code it gives me 1000 different animals like so (this is just the first 20 or so)
   [1] "dog"      "hamster"  "hamster"  "dog"      "goldfish" "goldfish" "dog"     
   [8] "goldfish" "dog"      "goldfish" "dog"      "dog"      "dog"      "dog"     
  [15] "cat"      "hamster"  "goldfish" "goldfish" "goldfish" "hamster"  "hamster"

Comment: What I want to do is count the number of times each of the four animals/strings appear in that specific sample, which won't be 250 exactly.

Comment: This isn't a statistical question; it is an R coding question. We will migrate this to SO for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try in R:

```
> table(pet)
pet
     cat      dog goldfish  hamster 
     241      284      225      250
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are creating this variable creates a vector of character data.  Consider:

```
> pet <- sample(c("dog","cat","hamster","goldfish"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
> str(pet)
 chr [1:1000] "cat" "dog" "dog" "goldfish" "dog" "dog" ...
```

You need a factor vector with specific levels.  Try:

```
> summary(as.factor(pet))
     cat      dog goldfish  hamster 
     252      244      252      252
```